# Magento - How to get current category name on product view Page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want current category name on product view Page.

How to get current category name on product view Page?

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/how-to-get-category-name-and-url-on-product-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A product can be attached with multiple category so directly not able to get current category of that product but if you visit category page and then goes to product page at that time category is in session so you can get category by

```
$_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');
echo  $_category_detail->getName();
```

if you are directly landing on a product page without accessing any category then there is no category in session so at that time you can get category of that product by

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    if(count($categoryIds) ){
        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);

        echo $_category->getName();
    }
```

Comment: In this i get first level current category but i want lower level category as current category.

Comment: You can reverse the category array. `array_reverse( $_product->getCategoryIds() );`